# How to ajax validate few form fields then submit natural way?/

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am in a situation where I have a form with some fields.

I have 5 input fields and I want to validate 2 fields which are **username** and **purchase code** using jquery ajax. If these two fields are valid, submit the form natural way like borwser does (not ajax).

Here is my jquery for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('#submit').click({status:'initial'}, function(e) {  

     e.preventDefault(); 

     $('.error').hide();
     $('.success').hide();

     // get data from form
     var username = $("input#username").val(); 
     var itemCode = $("input#itemCode").val(); 
     var dataString = 'username ='+ username + '&itemCode=' + itemCode;  

     $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "verify_purchase.php",  
      data: dataString,  
      success: function(html) {  

         // valid purchase
         if (html == 'valid') {
             form.submit();
         } else{
             // if wrong purchase details
             // do some stuff 
         };                  
      }  
    });  

});
```

The problem is when I submit form, ajax works perfectly but my form is not submitted afterwards like the way browsers submits the form.

Any help??

Comment: $('#form').trigger('submit'); 

this is not working either

Comment: did you check the data returned by jsno through console.log(html)? is it really == 'valid'?

Comment: yes the returned data is "valid". I have also tested by placing an alert inside if(html == 'valid'){alert('yes')} 
its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that you have, I think the error is this line:

```
form.submit();
```

I can’t see `form` defined anywhere. Going purely on the code you’ve supplied, you could do this instead:

```
$('#submit').parents('form').submit()
```

However, I think a better overall approach would be to add a `submit` event handler to the form, and stop the “natural” submission if validation fails, instead of dealing with the submit button’s `click` event. Depending on the form and the browser, it could be submitted by someone hitting return when in a text field, so the submit button’s click event isn’t necessarily reliable.

So, if you have a form like this:

```
<form id="my_form" action="purchase.php" method="post">
```

Then the script might look like this:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function (e) {
    $('.error').hide();
    $('.success').hide();

    // get data from form
    var username = $(this).find("input#username").val(); 
    var itemCode = $(this).find("input#itemCode").val(); 
    var dataString = 'username ='+ username + '&itemCode=' + itemCode;  

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        async: false,
        url: "verify_purchase.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        success: function(html) {  

        // valid purchase
        if (html == 'valid') {
            return true;
        } else{
            // if wrong purchase details
            e.preventDefault();

            // do some stuff
            return false;
        };                  
  } 
});
```

Comment: This is also I nice approach

Comment: sorry for off topic but i just checked your website: http://www.browsersupport.net/  bookmark it, usefull site thx :)

Comment: @roasted: cheers! (It’s long overdue an update though; you’ll want to check out caniuse.com too.) On `async:false`, isn’t that just when you’re making an AJAX call “with `jqXHR ($.Deferred)`”, as per [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

Comment: "Documentation updated to clarify that async: false is still allowed but that use with $.Deferred is deprecated."  You got it even i cannot think about any reason to use this option.

Comment: @roasted: yeah I’m not familiar with `$.Deferred`, so I don’t know how that would work/not work. (I would have been surprised if they deprecated synchronous HTTP requests in jQuery.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if the user has clicked a submit button, just use javascript to block a *natural submission* if the validation return an error.

So like this:

```
<form action="/somewhere.php" action="post" 
    onsubmit="return startValidatingForm();">
```

The javascript function would look something like:

```
function startValidatingForm(){
    // Do ajax and validation

    return html == "valid";
}
```

Now, if the ajax request found any error, the function returns `false` which will prevent the form from being actually submitted. If the function returns `true`, the form will be submitted the **natural way**.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
form.submit();
```

Try this:

```
//use $('#submit') not $(this) {ajax context}
$('#submit').off('click').click(); //this should reaffect native click behaviour on submit
```

Answer (score 0):

generally in order to submit a form you should supply its id to JQuery because JQuery needs a selector in order to find the element in the DOM and call a function on it. For example, you have a form looking like that:

```
<form id="orderForm" action="orderhandler.php" ...>
some fields...
</form>
```

here in order to submit the form via jQuery to write

```
$('form#orderForm').submit();
```

or

```
$('form#orderForm').trigger('submit');
```